# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () deployed react site made with vite on netlify and getting this error

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, netlify

I have an issue, my website seems to build and deploy fine but when I visit it, I recieve no asset images on my site. When I ckecked console I receive errors stating ‘Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()’.

I'm a beginner and tried various steps to fix it and searched various stackoverfow questions and reddit threads and even asked chatGPT but no good till now.

Website: https://clipboard-weebsite.netlify.app/
GitHub: https://github.com/Sujal-web/clipboard-website.git

Please help!

Comment: send the screenshot or code of the asset path, and how you import it in the project file

Comment: You are linking https://clipboard-weebsite.netlify.app/src/assets/images/clipboard-images/bg-header-desktop.png but the file is at https://clipboard-weebsite.netlify.app/images/clipboard-images/bg-header-desktop.png

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, if you need help please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello my beginner friend.
Thats src path does not work in react and specially in deployed project.
You should `import image from the "/src/assets/images/clipboard-images/logo-google.png"`
OR
You can use `public/images` folder and use public path to the each image if you want proceed in this way `<img src={'/images/clipboard-images/logo-google.png'} />`